# Password Hashing

Tags: computer-science

I am creating a web application which stores users passwords. I was wondering what are the best methods / algorithms that a programmer can use to hash passwords?

Comment: "best" is pretty vague -- what are you looking for?  Few collisions?  Security?  Performance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Key strengthening techniques such as [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) or [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) are generally considered better than plain hashes since cracking them requires more resources. The downside of this is that generating and verifying them also requires more resources; *your* resources.

Regardless of exactly which algorithm you choose, always use a suitable, per-user [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29).

Answer (score 3):

This is a related article...
http://www.h-online.com/security/features/Storing-passwords-in-uncrackable-form-1255576.html

and it mentions this tool...

http://www.openwall.com/phpass/

Maybe it helps you to get some ideas?!

**Edit:**

> [PHP 5.5 implements an API for secure password hashing!](https://gist.github.com/3707231)
>
> For PHP > 5.3.7 there is already a functions-set workaround to
>   implement the [API for secure password hashing](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to your scripts.