# bcrypt with salt how?

Tags: php, salt, crypt, bcrypt

I'm kind of new when it comes to security, I've been reading up on [php crypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) and searching for good advice though no one really goes into detail about "how" you go about doing it in the most effective way.

I made a test login which uses something like this:

```
 //verify login from user input
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$salt = '$2a$10$cdDegHjJLPUvVXYz23679.MOetNHBk9NTStpY9YjJWiL5ECfhHlSm';
$password = crypt(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']), $salt);
```

(I'm sure there's lots I need to change to make it fully secure (e.g restrict password string length) please enlighten me with anything else you think would be of good practice)

I read somewhere that it's ideal to make a random salt and store it with the password, (I don't fully understand that concept of checking a number that doesn't relate to the password)

Then I read somewhere that it's pointless to do a random salt because it won't increase the security, and that a static salt would do pretty much the same.

I saw this [tutorial](http://www.gregboggs.com/php-blowfish-random-salted-passwords/) usinga random salt with $_GET. (Tell me this is not right)

Can someone point me in the right direction of making my bcrypt as effective as possible.

Thanks

Comment: "Tell me this is not right" - which part?

Comment: Please don't blindly use `mysql_real_escape_string` everywhere. It should only be used to escape strings for queries (and it should be avoided anyway, you're safer when using prepared statements, and they are easier to get right for beginners). And yes, you should use a random salt per user.

Answer (score 2):

Using a random salt for each password **is** important. PHP's implementation of the `crypt()` function will include it automatically in the resulting hash value so there is no problem where to store it, but it should be generated correctly from a random source.

I wrote a small [article about bcrypt in PHP](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#ssl_bcrypt), because i think it's important that one understands how the function works. As soon as we understand it, we can use a well established library like [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/).

Answer (score 1):

See my old answer on this thread over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029372/). There is one interesting article and a link to phpass.

Comment: Thanks, I did come across it previously. It looks good, though I do want to get my hands dirty just so I know how to do it without an aid.

Comment: Eddy everywhere I go I keep ending up back at http://www.openwall.com/phpass/. (I'm wrong about the hands dirty thing), I should learn about security though I shouldn't use my own implementation I should use someone elses tried & tested system for serious projects as I will never become an expert overnight.

Comment: @Julien Etienne - No you where right, you _should_ get your hands dirty, and as soon as they are dirty enough, you can use a library. Often enough i ended up writing examples, i expected to find tons of articles in the internet, - i didn't find them, because nobody wants to get dirty hands.